# Chart is not rendering with Jqplot - Any ideas?

Tags: jquery, drupal, charts, jqplot

Does anyone have any idea why my chart is not being rendered with Jqplot?  I have followed all the instructions, yet it is just blank.

I am tearing my hair out here as I have done this successfully with another website, yest cannot seem to do it with this one....Maybe ive just missed something really really simple.

http://healthinteractive.co.uk/assess/node/1/done?sid=5

**EDIT**

This is the link the the same page but on a different website that I have done successfully in case anyone can see glaring differences between the two.

http://www.beatinganger.com/node/353/done?sid=781

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting some fatal errors in your JavaScript:

```
Uncaught #<Object>
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://healthinteractive.co.uk/assess/node/1/done?sid=5 from frame with URL http://www.facebook.com/sorry.php?msg=account. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

It looks like you're running a script from Facebook that may be conflicting with the jqplot script.

Comment: Thankyou, I removed the Facebook iframe script, yet it is still not rendering.  It's like it is not loading Jquery or something.

Comment: This link might help, it is the website which I have done it succesfffully http://www.beatinganger.com/node/353/done?sid=781

Comment: You're still getting the 'Uncaught #<Object>' error on line 1669 of jquery.jqplot.js

Comment: Thanks, that wasnt the problem - managed to sort it out in the end.  Needed to rename the input fields jqplot was rendering from. Stupid me!